# Datomic - how to retract all values of an attribute

Tags: clojure, datomic

I need to all the values of a particular attribute in an entity (for datomic schema). The retract function requires the attribute's value to be passed as argument but they are way too many, and I just require them to be replaced with new set of values. Is it possible to achieve via clojure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either query all values and generate the desired retraction in your peer or,  if you wish to ensure an "empty attrib" before new values are written, do the same from within a transaction function.

```
(map (fn [v] [:db/retract eid attrib v]) 
     (d/q '[:find [?v ...]
            :in $ ?e ?a
            :where [?e ?a ?v]
           db
           eid
           attrib))
```

Comment: Thanks Leon, I'll try it. Also could you also provide the snippet for doing the above within a transaction function (as you'd mentioned)

Comment: @Abhinav Just write a transaction function and use the snippet from inside - It's mostly boilerplate http://docs.datomic.com/database-functions.html